# How serialize xml with constant attribute in java?

Tags: java, xml

Consider a class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
class Dto {
    @XmlElement
    @Xml????("constantValue")
    private String field = "12345";
}
```

output should be

```
<root>
    <field myAttribute="constantValue">12345</field>
</root>
```

The question is what annotation to use instead of `Xml????`?

**Important note**

A lot of examples suggest to use `@XmlAttribute`, but this lead to create a wrapper like that:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
class Dto {
    @XmlElement
    private Wrapper field = new Wrapper("12345");
}

class Wrapper  {
    @XmlElement
    private String field;
    @XmlAttribute        
    private String myAttribute = "constantValue";  

    public Wrapper(String field) {
         this.field = field; 
    }
}
```

As you can see attribute is constant, so there is no need to create wrappers for every `String` field in the class. So `@XmlAttribute` attaches attribute to enclosing class and not unsuitable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`@XMLAttribute` is the only valid solution for this xml result. And if you use a DTO class you can easily map the data. Everything else is not jaxb.

```
public class XmlTest {

    @Test
    public void rootTest() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        Root root = new Root(new Field("constantValue", "123456"));

        marshaller.marshal(root, writer);

        System.out.println("Output: " + writer.toString());
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "root")
    public static class Root {

        @XmlElementRef(name = "field")
        Field field;

        public Root(Field field) {
            super();
            this.field = field;
        }
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "field")
    public static class Field {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "myAttribute")
        String myAttribute;

        @XmlValue
        String value;

        public Field(String myAttribute, String value) {
            super();
            this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```